# How to add an user element to users collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, foreach, push

I have users and venues. 
in table user_venue I store multiple connections (manyToMany)

```php
$rUsers = \DB::table('user_venue')->where('venue_id',$user->id)->get();

$resUsers = collect();

foreach ($rUsers as $key => $i) {
    $id = $i->user_id;
    $u = User::findOrFail($id);
    $resUsers->push($u);
}
```

As you can see I want to store `user` model into collection `$resUser` but its return me error page and don't load view...
WHy?

Comment: Can you post the fully code and error.

Answer (score 2):

When you are `$u->push($resUsers)` you are attempting to push into a single `User` record/instance. I believe you would like to do the following instead:

```
$resUsers->push($u);
```

This will push the single `User` record into the `$resUsers` collection.

Comment: yes, thanks. Just then I got an error - don't show my view.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a many-to-many relationship and want to load the `User`s linked with a given `Venue`, why don't you use a relationship? This is **more efficient** because you are hitting the database just once as opposed as your actual strategy.

```
# Venue.php

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
# VenueController.php

public function myFunction(Request $request)
{
    $venue = Venue::find('your-venue-id'); // getting a venue
    $users = $venue->users; // <-----

    return view('users')->with('users', $users);
}
```

In the above code the `$users` variable is an instance of [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections), this hold a collection of `User` models that match the query that, as far as I know, is your desired output.